# Spring Data REST - Implementing user detail service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to implement the user detail service to include audit data for the entities.

The `UserEntity` class is as follows:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Audited
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true,updatable = false)
    private String uuid;

    private String username;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;
}
```

I also have the following class which includes the audit meta data. This class will be extended by other entities.

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Audited
public class Auditable {

    @CreatedDate
    private Long createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Long lastModifiedDate;

    @CreatedBy
    private UserEntity createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private UserEntity modifiedBy;

}
```

Here is my user detail service.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<UserEntity> {

    @Autowired
    private AccessToken accessToken;

    @Autowired
    private UserEntityRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserEntity getCurrentAuditor() {

        UserEntity user = userRepo.findByUuid(accessToken.getSubject());
        return user;
    }

}
```

Now when I run the code I get the following error message.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: api.core.model.UserEntity, at table: business_entity, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(created_by)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.addValueInFirstPass(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:219) ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.addValue(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:345) ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.addProperties(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:371) ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.generateFirstPass(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:662) ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.EntitiesConfigurator.configure(EntitiesConfigurator.java:94) ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.doInitialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:152) ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:117) ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 171 common frames omitted
```

If I remove the `UserEntity` fields everything works fine and the audit data `createdDate` and `lastModifiedDate` are correctly recorded in the database.

I also included `@ManyToOne` annotation for UserEntity fields and the code runs fine but the database does not have the fields `createdBy` and `modifiedBy`. How do I fix this?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? would you please share your findings?

Comment: switched to @ManyToOne for the user columns, seems to work just fine

Answer (score -1):

we should have table called Auditable_aud.